# How to validate data before update in the recordset in Ms access VBA

Tags: json, vba, ms-access

After getting more information here, I think there is need to validate the data before storing in a stagnant table in Ms access. I’m not sure about this topic frankly its new to me , I’m just try to see whether it will work.

I want to check whether `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblEfdReceipts")` has data before proceeding to update , below is the full code:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblEfdReceipts")
    If lngStatus > 0 Then
    ElseIf lngStatus < 0 Then
        ' Handle error.
        On Error Resume Next
    End If
        ' Process data.
  Set JSONS = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strData)
    Z = 2
  For Each item In JSONS
           With rs

            .AddNew
            rs![TPIN] = item("TPIN")
            rs![TaxpayerName] = item("TaxpayerName")
            rs![Address] = item("Address")
            rs![ESDTime] = item("ESDTime")
            rs![TerminalID] = item("TerminalID")
            rs![InvoiceCode] = item("InvoiceCode")
            rs![InvoiceNumber] = item("InvoiceCode")
            rs![FiscalCode] = item("FiscalCode")
            rs![TalkTime] = item("TalkTime")
            rs![Operator] = item("Operator")
            rs![Taxlabel] = item("TaxItems")("TaxLabel")
            rs![CategoryName] = item("TaxItems")("CategoryName")
            rs![Rate] = item("TaxItems")("Rate")
            rs![TaxAmount] = item("TaxItems")("TaxAmount")
            rs![VerificationUrl] = item("TaxItems")("VerificationUrl")
            rs![INVID] = Me.InvoiceID
            rs.Update
        End With
        Z = Z + 1
    Next

      rs.Close
      Set rs = Nothing
      Set db = Nothing
      Set JSONS = Nothing
```

I’m trying this code but I’m not sure of how do it correctly, the received data is never part of the live until checked.

**Validation code require improvements**

```
rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
If Me.Recordset.RecordCount = 0 then 'checks for number of records
   msgbox "There is no records" 
End if
```

If the data is present then process it.

Comment: Getting the number of records in a recordset can be tricky at times. Read [this article](https://www.geeksengine.com/article/vba-get-record-count.html), especially the [link](https://www.geeksengine.com/article/recordcount-ado-recordset-vba.html) in the first method to understand the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *DCount*:

```vb
If DCount("*", "tblEfdReceipts") = 0 Then
    ' Table has no records.
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblEfdReceipts")

    ' <snip>
Else
    ' Table has records. Skip.
End if
```

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you can check EOF (end of file).

Thus:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblEfdReceipts")
if rs.EOF = True then
   ' no records
End If
```